# Cant get .innerHTML to work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working with ruby on rails and I want to test some things out.

I have used this simple code to change the innerHTML of my body:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "Work will you?";
```

It doesn't bring any results.

I know my javascript file works correctly because i tested it with the:  alert() function

When i put the document.body.innerHTML into my file it breaks the javascript (the alert no longer works)

Anybody knows whats could cause this??

Comment: Is the document.body element loaded yet? Is your javascript waiting on DOMContentLoad or onLoad for the window? Is you javascript placed at the bottom of your HTML document or in the header? Provide HTML and Javascript files.

Comment: @David I don't think you need to wait for anything for `document.body` to be ready. Can you explain why you think you need to wait to access `document.body`? @Xitcod13 Any errors on your console? Post the surrounding HTML

Comment: @JuanMendes because this: http://jsfiddle.net/L83mL/ the dom gets parsed top to bottom, if the javascript is in the <head> (i'm not arguing that it should be in the <head>), it will execute before the body exists unless it is attached to an event.

Comment: @David You are right. It is because i didnt wait for document to be ready. I guess someone can either make that an answer and ill accept it or give 1 vote down so people dont waste their time on this question

Comment: @KevinB I see, synchronous scripts in the head tag won't have access to `document.body`. I must have got it confused with accessing just `document` from inside the head tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be running your code from within the `<head>` tag. `document.body` doesn't exist at that point. You have to wait for the DOM to be ready. You can do that using something like jQuery's `$(document).ready()` http://jsfiddle.net/L83mL/

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1013842/david and https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b